# Counting exact (case insensitive) strings in a column of data, excluding cells with string matches present with other text

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, csv

I want to count all the cells in a column of a CSV file that contain an exact string, ideally using pandas if possible and using Python. I do not want to include cells that contain the string but also contain other characters, and I need it to be case insensitive.

I'm currently using `df['columnName'].str.contains('someString', case=False).sum()` but it counts cells that includes other text as well. I feel like this should be a commonly used function, but I can't seem to find anything that fits what I'm looking for on the web, so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**Example:**

If my CSV file had something like this:

| Row | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Apples |
| 3 | Apple and Orange |
| 4 | aPpLe |
| 5 | Banana |

And I wanted to count the number of times "Apple" is in the Fruit column, I want it to output 2, since row 1 and row 4 satisfy my condition that only "Apple" is in the cell and it is case insensitive. I do not want it to count row 3 because the row is not exactly just "Apple", and obviously row 2 and 5 do not match the string "Apple" and should also not be counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `str.lower` and `value_counts`:

```
df['Fruit'].str.lower().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
apple               2
apples              1
banana              1
apple and orange    1
Name: Fruit, dtype: int64
```

**Update:**

To get a specific value use:

```
df['Fruit'].str.lower().value_counts()['apple']
```

Or:

```
>>> df['Fruit'].str.contains('^apple$', case=False).sum()
2
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! How would I extract those numbers? Like say I want to use the count specifically for "apple" to do other stuff with it? I don't want to extract all the counts for other strings I'm not interested in, only select ones. Are these numbers stored somewhere or is it just for me to print it out and see, without affecting the original data?

Comment: @samster Edited my answer, check the **Update** part.

Comment: Thanks! The first option with str.lower() runs into problems when the value doesn't exist though (e.g. if there aren't any rows with 'apple'). How can I solve that issue? I won't know exactly what's in my input dataset but if there are no 'apple' values I should still be able to output 0 for it.

And for option 2 with str.contains (when I tried it separately from option 1), it's not counting the rows it should be counting for some reason, and just gives me an output of 0. Do you know why that might be the case? My line of code to count it is identical to yours, I just printed out the value.

Comment: @samster Are you testing on the same dataset?

Comment: Yes, I'm testing on the same dataset to complete the code, but afterwards the code should be able to be run on other files with different data for the same subjects (so column headers and in this example, fruit names, would still be the same, but their corresponding values in another column may not be from file to file).

Comment: @samster Try it again :)

Comment: I'm still getting the same error! Sadly. I'm not actually working with fruits, that was just an example, so I put the header of my column where you had it as 'fruit', and 'apple' with the string I'm looking for. The function should still work though cause everything else is the same

Comment: @samster Are there any trailing whitespaces?

Comment: Nope, you mean accidental white spaces before and/or after my desired string?

Comment: @samster Yes....

Comment: Yeah I triple checked those, everything's spelt correctly and I don't have any unwanted whitespaces anywhere :/ This is the first line of the error though: File "/Users/Me/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

Comment: @samster Hmm what's the error?

Comment: File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError:

Comment: @samster Hmm you left of at `KeyError`, what else is after

Comment: That's the error when the string doesn't exist in any of the rows of the CSV for the str.lower().value.counts()['stringName'] method

Comment: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "/Users/Me/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 853, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "/Users/Me/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 961, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "/Users/Me/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError:

Comment: That's what comes after the key error ^ Sorry I ran out of characters for the comment

Comment: @samster use `df['Fruit'].str.contains('^apple$', case=False).sum()`